# Laravel 5 View composer gives me an undefined variable error

Tags: view, composer-php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5, I am trying to output categories variable to a view but currently I am getting an undefined variable error.

Here is the code.

Firstly in config/app.php:

```
'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
```

In app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:

```
public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('partials.menu', function($view)
        {
            $view->with('categories', Category::all());
        });
    }
```

In partials/menu.blade.php:

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <li><a href="/store/category/{!! $category->id !!}">{!! $category->name !!}</a></li>
    @endforeach
    <li>Basket</li>
    <li>Checkout</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

and in store/products.php:

```
@include('partials.menu')
```

The exact error I get is: Undefined variable: categories any help resolving this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution

Comment: First of all if your view is not in main resources folder then mention your related path also like mine was in `theme/menu` but i have tried `menu` in view name, so check and give related path if needed.

Answer (score 6):

Try these commands

```
composer dump-autoload
or
php artisan cache:clear
or
php artisan config:clear
```

sometimes, these simple tricks help.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue was from your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`.

In your boot method, `view::composer` is meant to receive **an array of views** your composer should apply to. i.e. `View::composer(['partials.menu'], function($view) { .. }`

See the complete solution:

```
public function boot()
{
    View::composer(['partials.menu'], function($view)
    {
        $view->with('categories', Category::all());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the method "with" accepts an array as argument, instead try this !

```
$categories = Categories::all();
$view->with(compact('categories'));
```

Comment: Not really. `with` accepts string and array both. See [the source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/View/View.php#L177).

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the Categories class in the query correctly, just change `Categories::all()` to `\App\Categories::all()` assuming you didn't change the namespace.